# How to make spring webclient follow redirect with access token/authorization header?

Tags: spring-boot, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2, spring-webclient, clientcredential

We are using spring boot 2.4.5 with webflux and calling a service with client credentials grant type. What we noticed is that webclient is not following redirects.

How can we enable webclient to follow redirects where it can continue passing access token until it get the http 200?

Adding following code snippet does not pass the access token to redirected url and it is returning 401.

```
 WebClient.builder()
                .clientConnector(new ReactorClientHttpConnector(
                        HttpClient.create().followRedirect(true)
                ))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sensitive headers like the `Authorization` are removed from the initialized request when redirecting to a different domain.

You can use the following variant of `followRedirect(boolean)`:

```
followRedirect(boolean followRedirect, Consumer<HttpClientRequest> redirectRequestConsumer)
```

In order to re-add the `Authorization` header using `redirectRequestConsumer`.

For more details see the Javadoc [here](https://projectreactor.io/docs/netty/release/api/reactor/netty/http/client/HttpClient.html#followRedirect-boolean-java.util.function.Consumer-) and Reactor Netty documentation [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/web-reactive.html#webflux-client-builder-reactor).

Comment: Don't know where you folks are reading documentation but I am not seeing `followRedirect` anywhere on WebClient documentation. Could you please provide the code snippet in entirety?

Comment: @SriniMurthy Update made.